# How do i have Caps Lock switching keyboard layout and Shift+Caps Lock enabling Caps Lock?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

It's a pretty easy to get this behaivor using ubuntu - I just enable keyborard layout switching by Caps Lock and Shift+Caps Lock automatically become Caps Lock switcher. When using elementary I try this:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['Caps_Lock']"
```

and then Caps Lock both enables Caps Lock and switches keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to swap `Ctrl` and `Caps Lock`. **Keyboard -> Options -> Ctrl key position: Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock**. In order to use `Ctrl + \` to switch between keyboard layouts — **Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Universal Access: Next Keyboard Layout** (`Ctrl + \`). So wen you press `Caps Lock + \` layouts will change, when you press Ctrl(left) text input mode switches to upper/lower case.